# Passing Command line argument to Python program using IDLE?

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments, python-idle

I have downloaded a python file xxxxxx.py that is supposed to run on the command line by
typing: `python xxxxxx.py filename1 filename2`
and that should take these two files as arguments.

I was wondering if there is a way I can use IDLE to pass in these arguments. Is there a way other than setting `sys.argv` ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why people insist on thinking that IDLE is something useful.

Comment: Please, you can give me suggestions on an IDE that you think is useful for windows. I would appreciate that

Comment: You don't pass arguments in IDLE at run time.  It's easy to simply type your command at the command line.  What stops you from tying `python xxxxxx.py filename1 filename2` at the command line?  Or copying and pasting it at the command line?  Or using up-arrow to type it again at the command line?

Comment: @S.Lott how does one debug with breakpoints from the command line? With IDLE you can do that easily

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: I can't tell for everyone, but to me the main reason is that IDLE is accessible virtually everywhere. This would be my tool of choice to quickly illustrate/present the Python code snippet to someone else. I saw it being used for this very purpose at "PyCons".

Comment: As of 3.7.4 and 3.8.0b2, use Run ... Customized on the Run menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this from the command line with:

idle.py -r scriptname.py put arguments here

You can try a different IDE like ActivePython

Or you can patch IDLE:

http://bugs.python.org/issue5680

Comment: if I am on windows. my path now is C:\Python26...etc \ idlelib   so I can run idle. But the script is somewhere else and so it cannot find it, what should I do?

Comment: Never Mind! I just added the C:\Python26\Lib\idlelib to the path in the Advanced System Settings

Comment: Just modify sys.argv within your code. For example `sys.argv = ['scriptname.py', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']`

Comment: A revision of the patch for issue 5680 is in 3.7.4 and 3.8.b2 as Run => Run Customized.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the content of your Python file. If it is well-written, like:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

def process(files):
   for file in files:
       # ...

if __name__ == '__main__'
    # some error checking on sys.argv
    process(sys.argv[1:])
    sys.exit(0)
```

Then you could simply import the python file and run it like:

```
 import name_of_file

 # ...
       name_of_file.process([file1, file2, file3])
 # ...
```

So, it really depends on how it is written. If it isn't written well but you can edit it, I would refactor it so that it can be used as a library; otherwise, I would use the subprocess module to invoke the program.

Comment: I just want to pass argument on run time when I run the python script. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @SaherAhwal As of 3.7.4 and 3.8.0b2, use Run ... Customized on the Run menu.